# Why does my jQuery app work ONLY after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem Summary:** jQuery todo list app offers 3 functions; add items, edit items, and remove items. I can add items continuously, but cannot edit or remove items continuously. A single item can be edited or removed at a time. A page refresh is required to remove or edit another item. The goal is to have all 3 functions working without having to refresh the page. There are no error messages displayed in the console.

**What I have tried:** I have attempted to remove event listeners with .off() at the completion of a function and then reinitialize the event listeners after the fact. This does not seem to help or make things worse.

**Live Demonstration:** [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/JLDesignNetwork/full/MWmjQVR)

**jQuery:**

```js
function checkTodos() {
    // todos in the key of my localStorage
    let dataInLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    let todos;

    // check if it is null or not
    if (dataInLocalStorage == null) {
        todos = [];
        $('#notices').html(`<div class='card'>No list items exist yet. Use the input box on the left to add items.</div>`);
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(dataInLocalStorage);
        let html = "";
        todos.forEach((todo, index) => {
            html += `<div id='item-${index}' class='card' data-index='${index}'>${todo}</div>`;
        });
        $(".incomplete").empty().append(html);
        $('#notices').empty();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkTodos();
    
    // adding items in todos
    $("input").keydown((e) => {
        if (e.code === 'Enter' && $("input").val() !== "") {
            todo = $("input").val();
            let todosData = localStorage.getItem("todos");
            if (todosData == null) {
                todos = [];
            } else {
                todos = JSON.parse(todosData);
            }
            todos.push(todo);
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
            $("input").val("");
        }
        checkTodos();
    });
    
    // list item removal
    $('.incomplete > div').click((e) => {
        let id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        let selector = '#' + id;
        let todosData = localStorage.getItem('todos');
        let index = $(selector).attr('data-index'); 
        todos = JSON.parse(todosData);
        
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            if (confirm("Remove the list item?")) {
                todos.splice(index, 1);
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
                checkTodos();
            }
        }
    });

      // list item editing
    $('.incomplete > div').click((e) => {
        let id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        let selector = '#' + id;
        let k = $(selector).attr('data-index');
        let todosData = localStorage.getItem('todos');
        todos = JSON.parse(todosData);

        if (e.altKey) {            
            $(selector).attr('contenteditable','true');
            $(selector).keydown(function(evt) {
                if (evt.code === 'Enter') {
                    $(selector).removeAttr('contenteditable');
                    todos[k] = $(selector).html();
                    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
                    checkTodos();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your event handlers are only registered for items that exist when loading the page (after the first call to `checkTodos()`). You can use event delegation to also handle events on dynamically added items by replacing

`$('.incomplete > div').click((e) => { ... })`

`$('input').keydown((e) => { ... })`

with

`$(document).on('click', '.incomplete > div', (e) => { ... })`

`$(document).on('keydown', 'input', (e) => { ... })`

etc.